# How to remove double byte space from string in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode

I have a column in database table that holds Item Numbers. One of the item contains double byte space `**400-000361（SZ17-20)**`. When this item's details is exported from system, it removes this space in csv and shows Item Number like this `**400-000361(SZ17-20)**`

When I try to compare the exported data with the system's data using query it does not list this item because the number is now updated.
Is there any way I can ignore that double space character to get the matched item using Regular Expression or some other way ?
I tried following way but it does not work

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('400-000361（SZ17-20)', '\s{2,}', ' ') T FROM dual 
WHERE '400-000361(SZ17-20)' = TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('400-000361（SZ17-20)', '([[:space:]]{2,}|[[:cntrl:]])', ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a double space or a double-byte space, or in fact any space at all. You have a [fullwidth left parenthesis](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff08/index.htm), which is apparently being translated to a standard one in your export process.

You can see what you really have with `dump()`:

```
SELECT dump('400-000361（SZ17-20)', 1016) FROM dual;

Typ=96 Len=21 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 34,30,30,2d,30,30,30,33,36,31,ef,bc,88,53,5a,31,37,2d,32,30,29
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

and compare with the modified version:

```
SELECT dump('400-000361(SZ17-20)', 1016) FROM dual;

Typ=96 Len=19 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 34,30,30,2d,30,30,30,33,36,31,28,53,5a,31,37,2d,32,30,29
                                                                   ^^
```

You can convert your table data with `replace()` and the equivalent Unicode string:

```
SELECT REPLACE('400-000361（SZ17-20)', unistr('\ff08'), '(') T FROM dual 
WHERE '400-000361(SZ17-20)' = REPLACE('400-000361（SZ17-20)', unistr('\ff08'), '(')

400-000361(SZ17-20)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=08181d0349a97d7490bf4d33a0036f8f)